# replace last occurrence of string from csv using sed command

Tags: sed, ksh

So I am using report builder to generate csv file, which I need to format so that it displays the totals and subtotals correctly. Note totals and subtotal are calculated with report builder.
My csv when not formatted correctly. Below is the input file(.csv)
[InputFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbfSA.png)
Expected output: [ExpectedResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9gML.png)

Following command didn't work as the input file has last line as CRLF.
Update last line:

```
sed '$s/003/003,,,,,,,Total,/' $InputFile.csv > $InputFile.csv.tmp
```

Comment: consider reviewing [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question accordingly; in particular, provide sample input (properly formatted and without unwanted text, eg, `CRLF`), the code you've tried, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) desired output; in the meantime ... you need to provide a search/match that covers the entire line, eg, `sed '$s/^003.*$/003,,,,,,,Total,/'`; on the other hand, if you're attempting to generate actual totals then `sed` is the wrong tool ... consider `awk` or `perl`

Comment: Thank you. I am new here. Need some time to get to know. Please bear me till then. I am not using sed to calculate the totals. Its just display. The csv file generated from report builder, ignores the formatting. Therefore, I am creating a script tp format the csv file.